# In AngularJS How to send http success response(complete data in the response) to c# controller and Controller to View

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I need to send http success response data to C# controller and that controller to view and display in the view(another page).

This is my angularJs http code:

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'GuestSearch',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'Address': address, 'City': city, 'state': state, 'ZipCode':zipcode }
    }
    $http(req)
       .success(function (response) {
           $scope.mainServices = response;
           if($scope.mainServices == "")
           {
               $("#lbl_msg").html('No Services available for this Location.Please select different Location').fadeOut(9000);
           }

       })
       .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           console.error('Error while retrieving profile information ' + data);
       });
```

in  $scope.mainServices i am taking respone and i need to send that entire data which is available in $scope.mainServices to C# controller and that controller is

```
public ActionResult AllServices()
{
    return View();
}
```

and from this controller i need to display the entire data in AllServices view

Answer (score 0):

If this AngularJS code and C# controller belongs to same page, then populate AngularJS reponse in a HTML element and access this HTML element from controller.

Comment: No Angular JS code  is in one page and i need to send that respone to another page